# Is there any tool to remove rvalue reference but not lvalue refrence within the standard library?

Tags: c++, templates, reference, standard-library

Basically I want to this:

```
template<typename TYPE>
struct not_rvalue_reference{
    typedef std::conditional_t<std::is_rvalue_reference_v<TYPE>, std::remove_reference_t<TYPE>, TYPE> type;
};

template<typename TYPE>
using not_rvalue_reference_t = typename not_rvalue_reference<TYPE>::type;
```

So for what ever type, I would get either a non reference type or a lvalue reference type.

And I was wondering if such thing exists in the standard library, and if not and I have to use this, what is the best name for it?

Comment: What do you want to use this for?  This almost sounds like you are looking for `decltype(auto)` for a return type.

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike I need this tool for a deduction guide for a class which is based on a tuple. I want either to have ```tuple<type, type,...>``` or ```tuple<type&,type&,...>``` (also mix of those)  but not ```tuple<type&&, type&&,...>. I do not want this for a return type.

Comment: Is `remove_rvalue_reference` better name?

Comment: @康桓瑋 yes, that is indeed a better name. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consulting [the cppreference documentation for <type_traits>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits), it appears that there is not such a tool in the standard library. I agree with the commenter 康桓瑋 that `remove_rvalue_reference` is a good name for this. To reduce template instantiation overhead, I would recommend a more direct implementation:

```
template<typename T>
struct remove_rvalue_reference
{
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T>
struct remove_rvalue_reference<T&&>
{
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T>
using remove_rvalue_reference_t = remove_rvalue_reference<T>::type;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There should be a ```typename``` in the last line, after ```=```. I edited the answer, Please take a look.

Comment: @AKL - The `typename` is no longer needed here if you use latest C++ standard. See [Down with typename!](https://wg21.link/p0634)